I have a question about a mathematical coincidence
I’ve noticed that taking two prime numbers $x$ and $y$ given $y>x$, and computing $(x^y+y)-(y^x+x)$ gives a number that’s always divisible by $x$ and $y$, provided that $x$ and $y$ are prime.
For example, $$(3^5+5)-(5^3+3)=120,$$ and $$120=(3 \times 5) \times 8.$$
Does anyone have an idea why this could be true, and could one rigorously prove that this is true for all prime numbers?

How far in the table of primes did you search? One example is not very convincing.

$x^y-x$ is an integer multiple of $y$; $y^x-y$ is an integer multiple of $x$.

Further to peterwhy's comment, see Fermat's little theorem.
